# SignUp ViewController With Steps. How to best way

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, parse-platform, uicontainerview

I am creating a registration page in my app, using parse.com for data management .. In this view controller I have a container view which should show three different viewController in sequence when the user clicks on the "Next Step "in a few words .. I'm trying to make a recording made with three steps.

I'm looking on the net but I can not find anything clear, can anyone help me find the right way to figure out how to show three-View-Controller in a ContainerView and show them through the use of a button?

Comment: You could have 3 subviews can't you ? signupView1, signupView2, signupView3 and show/hide them in the order you need.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply ... I've been meaning to do something like this to make you understand ... https://github.com/CooperRS/RMStepsController

Comment: what I wanted to do is to call the view controller in ContainerView through the use of self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier